# Can I have partial payments?

Tags: 8, commerce

Can I have partial payments in Drupal Commerce 2.x?

For example, the customers need to make a deposit of 10% up front; when they pick up the bought items, they need to pay the remaining amount. They can pay using either cash or bank transfer.